# Binding Paper-Tabs to Core-Pages with Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm building a site with Polymer that uses paper-tabs and core-pages. The problem I'm running into is that I can not seem to get the click event for the tabs to affect the pages being shown and all content remains hidden unless I specifically select which page I want shown.
So I really just want the tabs to behave the way tabs are supposed to behave.

Here is my code so far:

```
<body unresolved>

  <paper-tabs selected="0" selectedindex="0"  id="paper-tabs"  >

    <paper-tab id="paper-tab" active>ABOUT</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab id="paper-tab1">PORTFOLIO</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab id="paper-tab2">CONTACT</paper-tab>

  </paper-tabs>



  <core-pages selected="{{$.paper-tab.selected}} " selectedindex="0" notap  id="core-pages">
    <about-me id="paper-tab" active>
      <h2 horizontal center-justified>Worldwide Jamie</h2>
      <p>Jamie is a Chicago-based freelance front end web developer.</p>
      <p>Clearly this website is <b>Under Development</b></p>
      <p>Come back soon to see how great your site could be</p>
    </about-me>

    <portfolio-list id="portfolio">
    <!--Insert slider?-->
    </portfolio-list>

    <contact-me id="contact">
    </contact-me>
  </core-pages>    

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any time and consideration.

Comment: It seems there are many answers to your question. If your question has been answered you can accept one of them as an answer. Just click the check mark.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Polymer 1.0+, this is what you'll want to be using.

```
<link rel="import" href="components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">

<paper-tabs selected="0">
    <paper-tab>Tab One</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>Tab Two</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<iron-pages selected="0">
    <div>Page One</div>
    <div>Page Two</div>
</iron-pages>

<script>
     var pages = document.querySelector('iron-pages');
     var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');

    tabs.addEventListener('iron-select', function() { 
        pages.selected = tabs.selected;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: keeping `selected={{selected}}` in both tabs, pages binds the selection. Can you suggest how to set the default selected page when rendered in the start

Comment: @sivatumma, see here for an example: https://github.com/Download/polymer-cdn/blob/master/lib/paper-tabs/demo/tabs-with-content-example.html

Answer (score 8):

Simple. use this in your script.

```
var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');
var pages = document.querySelector('core-pages');

tabs.addEventListener('core-select',function(){
  pages.selected = tabs.selected;
});
```

Comment: With Polymer 1.0 this is `iron-pages` and `iron-select`, respectively.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag Good point. I have not edited the answer for Polymer  1.0 yet. But it looks like the OP is using 0.5.

Answer (score 6):

[Demo - Codepen.](http://codepen.io/DonSinDRom/full/azdbwM/)

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    /* some css */
    </style>

    <section layout vertical is="auto-binding">
      <paper-tabs selected="{{ selected }}" selectedindex="0" horizontal center layout>
        <paper-tab inline flex center-center horizontal layout active>First</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab inline flex center-center horizontal layout>Second</paper-tab>
        ...
      </paper-tabs>
      <core-animated-pages selected="{{ selected }}" selectedindex="0" notap>
        <section active one flex vertical layout>
            <--some html-->
        </section>
        <section one flex horizontal layout>
          <--some html-->
        </section>
        ...
      </core-animated-pages>
    </section>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      selected: 0
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: Nice, but the demo is probably outdated.

Answer (score 3):

The binding on `<core-pages>` is not being evaluated because data binding is only set up for definitions inside of a `<polymer-element>` template.

Polymer has a special "auto-binding" template that is meant to be put in the main page and provide data-binding for top level elements.

More info: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#bindingoutside

Comment: To leverage data binding outside of a <polymer-element>, put your stuff inside an auto-binding <template> element. Code example: https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html#autobinding

Answer (score 3):

- There's a typo in your core-pages 'selected' attribute expression: *paper-tab* instead of *paper-tabs*
- There's a trailing space behind this expression
- You cannot use `paper-tabs` as a property name. Rename the *paper-tabs* id to `paperTabs` (btw. is there a way to make Polymer print an error message in case of a malformed expression?)
- As @dfreedm said, you cannot use data binding outside a polymer-element. Another option is: put your whole app into a polymer-element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<template is="auto-binding">

   ...

  <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" selectedIndex="0"  id="paper-tabs"  >

   ...

  <core-pages selected="{{selected}}" notap  id="core-pages">

   ...

</template>
```

and, to add to some other things mentioned in other answers — i think `paper-tab` element shouldn't have `active` attribute