# Polymer 1.0 paper-tabs addEventListener stops binding tabs dynamically

Tags: polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am trying very basic tab switching and tab content. Here is my code:

A Custom element I built to generate Tab Strips dynamically

```html
<dom-module id="tab-generator">
  <template>
      <paper-tabs selected="{{defaultindex}}" id="tabstrip">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tabitems}}">
              <paper-tab>{{item.name}}</paper-tab>
          </template>
      </paper-tabs>
  </template>
  <script>
      (function () {
          'use strict';
          var pages = document.querySelector("#plantContent");
          var tabs = this.$.tabstrip;

          tabs.addEventListener('iron-select', function () {
              pages.selected = tabs.selected;
          });

          Polymer({
              is: 'tab-generator',

              properties: {
                  tabitems: {
                      type: Array,
                      notify: true
                  },

                  defaultindex: {
                      type: String,
                      notify: true
                  }
              }
          });
      })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

From `index.html` I am referencing this as follows:

```html
<paper-card heading="Dynamic Tabs">
  <div class="card-content">
    <tab-generator selected="0" tabitems='[{"name": "Plant Genus"}, {"name": "Plant Series"}, {"name": "Plant Species"}]'></tab-generator>
  <!-- iron pages to associate tabs as contents -->
    <iron-pages selected="0" id="plantContent">
      <div>Content - Tab 1</div>
      <div>Content - Tab 2</div>
      <div>Content - Tab 3</div>
    </iron-pages>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

Tabs bind fine before I added the following snippet in my custom element:

```html
<script>
  var pages = document.querySelector("#plantContent");
  var tabs = document.querySelector("paper-tabs");

  tabs.addEventListener('iron-select', function () {
    pages.selected = tabs.selected;
  });
</script>
```

But when I remove the `event listener` snippet i.e.

```html
tabs.addEventListener('iron-select', function () {
  pages.selected = tabs.selected;
});
```

tabs are back again.

I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688986/binding-paper-tabs-to-core-pages-with-polymer/33266798#33266798) post. What is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I would re-write your code to the following:

**tab-generator.html**:

```
<dom-module id="tab-generator">
  <template>
      <paper-tabs selected="{{selectedTab}}">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tabItems}}">
              <paper-tab>{{item.name}}</paper-tab>
          </template>
      </paper-tabs>
  </template>
  <script>
          Polymer({
              is: 'tab-generator',

              properties: {
                  tabItems: {
                      type: Array,
                      notify: true
                  },

                  selectedTab: {
                      type: String,
                      notify: true
                  }
              }
          });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**index.html**:

```
<paper-card heading="Dynamic Tabs">
  <div class="card-content">
    <tab-generator selected-tab="{{selectedTab}}" tab-items='[{"name": "Plant Genus"}, {"name": "Plant Series"}, {"name": "Plant Species"}]'></tab-generator>
  <!-- iron pages to associate tabs as contents -->
    <iron-pages selected="{{selectedTab}}" id="plantContent">
      <div>Content - Tab 1</div>
      <div>Content - Tab 2</div>
      <div>Content - Tab 3</div>
    </iron-pages>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

You should in your `index.html` also have property named `selectedTab`. What happens now is that, when you change `selectedTab` inside the `tab-generator.html` it is propogated to the property `selectedTab` inside `index.html` and will update the UI accordingly. No javascript is needed. :)